# Squashing Git commits after merging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-rewrite-history

I have a feature branch that has a few commits (see below). Since branching, a few commits have been added to master too.

So I merged `master` into the `feature` branch.

```
git checkout feature
git merge master
```

This results in the below log history on the `feature` branch:

```
*    E (HEAD) merging master into feature
|\
| *  D feature commit 2
| |
| *  C feature commit 1
* |  B master commit 2
|/
*    A master commit 1
```

In reality the number of commits on the feature path is large (100+) and I'd like to squash them all.

Is there a way to just squash the commits on the feature branch only while preserving those on the `master` line?

Comment: Do you still want the result to have one commit on the feature branch and merge with master, or do you want all your work to be applied on master without branching?

Comment: I think the first (if I understood correctly). Basically in the diagram above C and D should be squashed into one commit and the commits pulled in from `master` (A, B) should be preserved. This way I can merge C->D->E directly into `master` from this branch. Thanks again!

Comment: Another question - is your history on the feature branch perfectly linear, or does it have incoming or outgoing merges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. So you want to turn the commit graph in your question into this new graph:

```
*    E (HEAD) merging master into feature
|\
| *  D feature commit (squashes 1 and 2)
* |  B master commit 2
|/
*    A master commit 1
```

The procedure:

1. Ensure your working tree is clean. No uncommitted changes, no staged changes, no untracked files.
2. Ensure you are on the feature branch.
3. `git reset --hard  *Hash of D on feature branch*`
4. `git reset --soft  *Hash of A on master*`
5. `git commit` with the message you desire.
6. `git merge master`

Comment: Don't forget to stage the changes after #4

Comment: @CodyStott The staging is already implied by the soft reset, though

Comment: Ah good point, I never used the `soft` option before. Nice to know.

Comment: after #6 the there is still missing the link between 'B' and 'E', Tha branch master still is on 'B'. To get that done use something like `git checkout master` and `git reset --hard feature`

Answer (score 0):

Iff the Question adresses just the case where all commits just live in the local repository, the Question is (apart from my coment) solved. In case only a locale git repository is involved it is aquivalent to:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i
      // mark all commits to be squashed
git merge master
```

but you should resets masterbranch to `E` in order to publish your changes:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard feature
```

or (iff you really prefer to work with the comitish) `git reset --hard *Hash of E*`. I'm going to check weather the use of `git reset` works if `C` was already pushed to the remote repository.