# How to achieve simplified merge-commits

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Rational: In out environment review takes place on the branch that is here denoted as `master>`. I would like to squash (better: combine) commits together in order to have all changes to a certain development-step together. Thus:

How do I get from left to right?

```
                                                   master> * C <feature  
                                                           |\
            * H <feature   - just local                    | * H     (merged)
            |                                              | |
            * G     - pushed to remote          =??=>      | * G     (merged)
master> B * |       - pushed to remote                   B * |
          | * F     - pushed to remote                     | * F     (merged)
          |/                                               |/
          *                                              A *
```

In reality the number of commits on the feature path is large (10+) and I'd like to squash them all. Parts of them are already published to the remote repository (and should not be changed or altered). However I just want to create one single commit on the master branch.

`git merge --squash` apparently performs this, but it does not does not mark the commits as merged. Thus if I continue work on `<feature`-Branch the next call to `git merge` will lead to lots of conflicts. I found an [explanation on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25387972/11097806): `git merge --squash` leads to a patch unrelated to the source-commits.

So, what I want to achieve is to get from the right to the left situation and all commits on featurebranch (`F`, `G` and `H`) will be marked as merged*) - if I continue working on the Featurebranch next merge does not lead to conflicts with my own changes. This Question is solved, in case all Changes on the Featurebranch are not published to the remote repository (see [`git merge --squash`-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512202/squashing-git-commits-after-merging/59770090#59770090) ).

PS: Of course it would be sufficient to mark the commits individually as merged, but I neither know how to do this, nor how git manages it's merge information.

PSS: Normal merge does it, but it fails iff there is no commit on master.

*): "marked as merged" means, that in gitk - iff you select the commit, the list of branches includes feature, remotes/origin/feature, master, remotes/origin/master. As result those commits wont be considered in subsequent call to `git merge`.

Comment: Just delete your feature branch once you've merged it? Apart from that it's not clear what your expected outcome is?

Comment: Thanks @Liam, but I should continue working on this branch. (S'thing in the way the working environment is set up makes its costly to make a new branch for a single project - CICD is tied up to the named branch I'm working on, due to collaboration with a bunch of other executables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I learned the following: `git` will select the method how to merge based on the state of the involved Branches - In the trivial (*figure b) from my sketch below*) git selects *fast-foreward*, thats when only one of the two branches has changes. In this case it might occure, that all changes from the feater-branch will be placed on top of the master branch.

Off-topic: If there are changes on more than one of the involved branches (*figure a) from my sketch below*) git selects a *merge-Strategie* according to the current state of the involved branches and the git-configuration. In additon You migt use the commandline to enforce certain behavior (https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies or http://gitbu.ch/ch03.html).

With this knowlege there is an answer to my questions:

**Answer:** favor `--no-ff` over `--squash` If ever I want to avoid "fast-forward" merge you should use

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit feature
```

and after this you should syncronize feature to main

```
git checkout feature
git merge --ff-only master
```

this brings you from left to right off the sketch in the Question AND each commit original made to the `feature`-Branch will be marked as Present on the `master` branch (This info is displayed in gitk when you select the commit).

There might be another reason to avoid "fast-foreward": The achieved situation will document, wich changes are originally checked in to the feature-Branch and which are done to the main-Branch.

**Sketch to illustrate fast-foreward:**

```
    a) real merge                          b) trivial - no chanes on master

                * H <feature                           * H <feature
                |                                      |
                * G <feature/origin                    * G  <feature/origin
    master> B * |                                      |
              | * F                                    * F 
              |/                                      /
              *                            master> A *
```

`a)` is the usual case whith commits on both sides where a mergestrategi is involved to resolve 'em. `b)` is the trivial case, where fast foreward is posible.

**Summary:** In either case the given commands combines all the work commitet on the `feature` branch to a single commit on `master` without loosing the merge information.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you want to do.

When Git does a merge, it computes the merge base, which is *roughly* the common ancestor commit of both branches.  The three (and only) three points considered in a typical merge are the merge base and the two heads.  If you do a normal merge, then you'll produce a new commit on the main branch, and that commit or one of its descendants will usually be used as the merge base in the future, which means Git doesn't consider your changes a second time.

If you do a squash merge, then the merge base is the original fork point, so subsequent merges see you as having made multiple commits with identical changes, causing conflicts like you're seeing.

Unless you use a custom merge driver, you can't customize the merge base detection, so you need to adopt another solution or learn to deal with the conflicts.

What you can do is delete the existing branch and recreate it off the `master` branch (or just reset it to the latest commit on `master`), which will mean that future work is based off a commit including all previous work.  That will avoid your conflicts.

You can also use a standard merge instead of a squash merge, which will make the merge base detection do the right thing.

Finally, you could write a custom merge driver that somehow intuits information about your branch.  I wouldn't recommend this approach because it involves a lot of work and it's really easy to get wrong and mess up all your data.

But ultimately, given your workflow constraints, there are not a lot of options available to you.  I personally suggest a different, more standard workflow with less constraints; logical, independent commits; and a standard merge policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your descriptions (both the picture and your words) call for a regular merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

If that is not what you want and you insist in a squashed commit, then you cannot continue your work on branch `feature`, but must fork a new feature branch from `master` as soon as it has the squash-merged old feature branch.

Comment: Thanks @j6t, but that won't leed to the desired result. Unfortunatly you don't clearify why git can't mark the original commits as merged when doing a squashed merge. Do you have a clue where it stores it's merge information?

Comment: @Xantopp: unfortunately, *nothing* will lead to your desired result. Git is not capable of achieving what you want. Your CI/CD system is making one set of assumptions, and Git is making another, and the two do not combine well.

Comment: The following command enforces a squashed commit, even iff fast-foreward is possible: git merge --no-ff  feature

Comment: Please get your wording straight. A "squashed merge" with `git merge --squash` creates a single non-merge commit and loses the information which parent commits were merged. `git merge --no-ff` does not do that; it creates a regular merge commit, not a "squashed merge" commit, and keeps the information which commits were merged.